# Spring MVC video download ranged

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, video

I am building a video streaming web application. It uses an HTML5 video player. In order to prevent loading the entire file into memory, I am using the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/{videoId}" )
public void downloadVideo(
    @PathVariable(value = "videoId") long videoId,
    HttpServletResponse response) {

    Video video = getVideo(videoId);
    response.setContentLength((int) video.getSize());
    response.setContentType(video.getMimeType());

    Iterable<byte[]> fileContents = video.getContents();

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    for (byte[] bytes : fileContents) {
        outputStream.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

`video.getContents()` returns a custom buffered object which can be treated as an iterable array of bytes (could also be a BufferedInputStream). The video stream works great when you start playing from the beginning.

However when you skip forward or rewind in the video, the browser sends a range header `Range: bytes=23432-`. When this happens, it fails with the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`.

How do I modify this to work for ranged queries.

Comment: have you tried `response.getOutputStream().flush();` after finishing `for`.